# How can I convert an Atlassian Stash repo URL to open in the browser?

Tags: git, bash, bitbucket-server

Atlassian Stash uses repo URLs for cloning/pushing/pulling in the form of

```
https://mystashserver/scm/myproject/myrepo.git
```

How can I transform this URL into the one used by Stash's web UI in the form of

```
https://mystashserver/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo
```

Opening the first URL in the browser automatically forwards to the latter, but you can't add additional parameters, e.g. for selecting a specific branch.

I'm looking for a way to transform URLs of the first kind to the latter, ideally for use in a Bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in a Bash script, using Bash's built-in regular expression support:

```
giturl=https://mystashserver/scm/myproject/myrepo.git

re='(.*)/scm/(.*)/(.*)\.git'
if [[ $giturl =~ $re ]]; then
  newgiturl=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/projects/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/repos/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  echo $newgiturl
fi
```

The regular expression splits up the original URL into several parts:

- (Capture Group 1): Protocol, hostname, optional web root context
- "scm": This seems to be a fixed value for Atlassian Stash
- (Capture Group 2): The project name
- (Capture Group 3): The actual repository name, minus the `.git` suffix

In the above example, the `newgiturl` variable then reassembles the URL, injecting the `projects` and `repos` part in the desired locations.